Android AVD Issue - Not starting
Issue:
I recently got an HP laptop (i7-7500U with 16GB RAM and 512GB SSD), but I can't start the AVD. I've tried different Android versions and phone models, including both Play Store versions and normal ones, but I'm still facing the same issue.

Pictures:
After running the AVD, it takes a while to start, and once it does, all I see is a glitchy screen. I have tried running different Android versions, including:
Pixel 6 Pro API 34
Pixel 4 API 31

Little history:
When I first tried running it, the AVD failed to start because VMX was not enabled by default on the laptop. I enabled it from the startup menu. After that, when I tried running the AVD, I faced the issue mentioned above.
I have updated the drivers for both GPUs (Intel and AMD) and updated the BIOS to the latest version listed on the HP website. I also tried setting the graphics to hardware acceleration, but that didn't help.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. I don't know if it's an issue related to the laptop or the emulator software in general. This might be a simple fix, but I can't find the fix.
